# Eclipse RAP multi-window/tab

Tags: eclipse, tabs, window, rcp, eclipse-rap

I would like to have a multi-tab/windowed Eclipse RAP application.

I am able to open a second window using

```java
UrlLauncher launcher = RWT.getClient().getService(UrlLauncher.class);
launcher.openURL("/gasf?foo=other_perspective");
```

Where I use the foo paramter to select the perspetive I want. However using this method will create a speparate http session, thus the various listeners and so on won't communicate with my first window.

I also tried opening a second window/page using

PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().openPage("other_perspective" , null);

But this merely changes the current window perspective but does not open a second window or tab in my browser.

Has anyone achieved a multi-tab RAP application with working selectionlisteners between the tabs?

Thanks for any help you can provide

***EDIT:***
THANKS a lot **ralfstx**, as you pointed out, I can share the listeners or anything using the shared HTTP session, so far so good. Now the next step is to be able to update a tab based on an external event.

To try my idea of refresh from another tab, I did a dummy timer that does something 2 seconds later (i.e. simulate something triggered from another tab) with:

```java
final ServerPushSession pushSession = new ServerPushSession();
pushSession.start();   
Display display = Display.getDefault();
NavigationView navigationView = ((NavigationView) window.getActivePage().findView(NavigationView.ID));
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        navigationView.doSomething();
      }
    });
  }
}, 2000);
```

This works! The `pushSession.start()` forces the UI to refresh without any user interaction. So now the action `doSomething()` is executed on the navigationView as soon as the 2 seconds are reached.

My only remaining concern is how much load this puts on the server, but its a reasonable solution at least. I validated your answer.

***EDIT2:***
Just to be complete, to make sure not bump in an invalid Thread access error since we are updating a display from another display, in the `doSomething()` method we must execute actions using `display.asyncExec`:

```java
Display display = Display.getCurrent();
public void doSomething() { 
    display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            treeViewer.refresh();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current architecture of RAP, you can't spread workbench windows over different browser tabs. Every new browser starts a new `UISession` which implies another `Display` (see [Scopes in RAP](https://www.eclipse.org/rap/developers-guide/devguide.php?topic=scopes.html&version=3.0)).

However, the `HttpSession` should be the same (unless you have cookies turned off), so you could use this as a means of communicating between different browser tabs.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, okay that's a good starting point, so my follow-up question would be, is it possible to trigger an event on the UI of one tab without any click by the user. My idea here is to have the events from another tab call a refresh (or something else) on the tab?

Comment: Edited my question that answers my folloowup queston :) Thanks!

Comment: Yes, using ServerPush is the only way to update the UI without a user interaction. On the server, it keeps a request socket open, so yes, there is some overhead, plus some proxies don't like long-standing requests. That's why we recommend to active SP it only while it's needed (e.g. to show progress for running operation etc.)

Comment: Okay thanks, I will add code to only start ServerPush when multiple tabs are actually involved. I also edited my question for readers to know how to get rid of the invalid thread access that will occur if they use multiple tabs as I do. Thanks for your inputs, it works well not for me. Cheers